# concatenate string arrays - algorithm flowchart interpretation

Tags: flowchart

I would like help interpreting this flowchart. I don't know what *k* means even though they say what it represents in the question.

I can quickly see that since dimension *m* corresponds to variable X that the first loop has to be iterating on X. Therefore **A** has to be **X(k) → Z(k)**.

Since I know the first loop is on X, obviously the second loop is on Y. Therefore **B** is **Y(k) → Z(?+k)**.

Where I get stuck is choosing (**m**+k) or (**n**+k). What exactly does *k* represent? 
 The question says that variable *k* varies from 1 to m by 1.

*m* is the number of elements in the array (the dimension).
*k* is the iterator?
`variable k varies from 1 to m by 1`means that *k* varies from 1 element to *m* elements right?
I know the answer is (**m**+k) but why isn't it (**n**+k)?

If possible could you please explain it in *both* C & Java using the same variable names? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The note to the right of the flowchart says that variable K varies by 1 to m in loop two (just like loop 1), but that's not entirely true; it varies by 1 to **n**.

Comment: I thought the same thing. It's just their wording. They mean to say that just like Loop 1 varies by m, Loop 2 varies by n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's decouple, a bit, the iteration ranges (e.g. for loop control variable `k`) and what they are iterating over.

Technically, the loop control variable(s) iterate over a range of integers, e.g. 1..m or 1..n (rather than over elements of the arrays).

So, a loop, via its loop control variable, nominally iterates over a range of integers, not necessarily elements of an array, though it can be used to iterate through array elements, within the body of the loop, by using subscripting/indexing expressions like `X(k)` and `Z(k)` in terms of the loop control variable.

> What exactly does k represent?

There is no reason that the question has to have used the same variable name, `k`, for both for-loops — *but because it does* use `k` twice (rather than, say, `k1` first loop and `k2` later), `k` means two different things in two different places.  In Loop 1 `k` is an index ranging from `1` to `m`, *which is the range of `X`*, and in Loop 2, `k` is an index ranging from `1` to `n`, *which is the range of `Y`*.

> `m` is the number of elements in the array (the dimension)

Specifically, in the array `X` — whereas `n` is the number in `Y`.

You already realize that the concatenation operation is concatenating `X` with `Y` not vice versa.  Loop 1 then merely copies `X` into (the first part of) `Z`, character by character, and thus at each `k`, a copy from `X` into the same position in `Z`.

Next, Loop 2 copies `Y` into `Z` — but where to place the elements in `Z`, given that `X` has already been copied into `Z`?

In words, the answer is that the copy of (concatenation of) `Y` should go after the copy of `X` in `Z`.

In variables, that translates such that the first element of `Y` should go to the `Z` position at `m` because `m` is (firstly) the length of `X`, and also (secondly), it is where Loop 1 left off/stopped in `Z` — in other words, just after loop 1 finishes, `m` identifies the boundary between the last position used and the first free position in `Z`.  Since we want to copy the whole of `Y` into `Z`, then all the characters of `Y` *come from `k`* but *go to `m + k` in `Z`*.

So, to recap, `m` is not only the size of `X`, but also where Loop 1 finished copying into `Z`.  `n` is merely the size of `Y`.  Note that `X`'s copy in `Z` after Loop 1 now occupies `Z(1..m)`, so then, the location where we want `Y(1)` to go is `Z(m + 1)`, `Y(2)` to `Z(m + 2)`, and so on, so that characters of `Y` are all placed after the entire copy of `X` in `Z`.

The copy of `X` in `Z` occupies `Z(1..m)` and the copy of `Y` in `Z` occupies `Z(m..m+n)`, which is saying that the copy of `X`'s comes first and the copy of `Y` comes directly after the copy of `X`.

(If you work through a real example, e.g. concatenate "hi " with "world", you'll see how this comes together.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already understand how the algo works, but didn't get what `k` was doing since I'm not actually seeing it in code. I'm not a CS student so often if I don't see it in code, I think of it as a trick question lol. I guess I already correctly guessed what `k` was.  `k` is the iteration index position so basically after all `m` elements are added to `Z`, `n` elements get added according to `k` position? Is that correct? And `n` has no purpose anymore since it's just the dimension of  `Y`.

Comment: So in my experience a loop control variable is often `i`. Of course it can be anything but `i` seems to be most prevalent at least in my web/mobile world. This question mentions the `i-th` character and `i-th` element which to me seems like they're using  `i` as the loop control variable. Why did they use `k` instead of `i` in the loop flowchart? Is `k` often used in flowcharts to represent `i` in code?

Comment: 1. Yes, that is correct.  As I mentioned, it is unnecessarily confusing to use `k` twice for both loop 1 & 2: they could have used `i` for loop 1 and `j` for loop 2 and that might have been easier to follow.  However to be clear, it is common practice especially in older code to reuse a variable when the two usages don't conflict.  In newer code, `k` might have the same name but actually be two separate variables, one each in the context of the separate loops.

Comment: 2. I can't explain why they choose `k`.  It is common since the days of Fortran in the ~50's, ~60's and ~70's, to use integer (index) variables named i, j, k.  This is also common in math & logic, and they are evoking this in their description of i-th element (e.g. forall i : if i < m then X[i] == Z[i]).  They could have used `k` there as well, but for some reason didn't!

Comment: Awesome. Basically it was just their language that confused me then. Makes me feel much better. Great explanation. Thank you.

Comment: What topic category is this in programming? Data flowcharts? Algorithm flowcharts? I want to study more examples like this. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest looking for algorithms and data structures.